# What does playing the anchor role mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context

Can someone explain to me the meaning of the following phrase:

> You have to be more responsible, because you are going to play anchor
>   role in the new project.

My manager said this to me. How should I take it? Was it complimentary or derisive or what?

Comment: This simply means you are going to spearhead the project. IMO, it could be considered complimentary if it meant a promotion or upward role movement. Otherwise, it is just a precaution so as not to mess things up. It depends entirely on the context and the facial expressions of the speaker, to some extent!

Comment: Well, "spearhead" is just as figurative as "anchor".

Comment: You are going to be quarterbacking the project.

Comment: Basically you're going to be the "team leader" or "head technical guy" or whatever -- the person that others turn to and rely on for guidance, and the person who keeps the project on track.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation BiscuitBoy, and he told that via messenger.

Comment: The expression likely comes from a [relay race](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchor_leg) where one of the racers is the "anchor" who typically completes the final (and therefore most competitive) leg of the race.

Comment: The first part of the sentence (*You have to be more responsible*) sounds like a reproach. The second part (*you are going to play anchor role in the new project*) is positive:  you will be a major player in the new project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **anchor:**
>
> a person or thing that can be relied on for support, stability, or security; mainstay (definition number five in [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anchor?s=t)

Congrats, you're going to be the go-to guy.

Comment: @Araucaria: I did? I must have been drunk. My apologies.

Comment: @Araucaria: Sure thing. I do tend to be absentminded now and then. Not very often. Once again, my apologies.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Ricky, your answer gave me positive views and enthusiasm

Answer (score 0):

Here the manager means nearly "the boat anchor" like role.

**An anchor is a connecting device that is used to connect a boat and seabed.**

An anchor holds the ship or boat and don't let it go away in water. Your manager means the same for you in the statement above. I think you are going to be the key person of the new project and you are the one on whole project relies. You are the **anchor** for the new project.